# Why is Facebook resolving a Twitter URL improperly?

Tags: ajax, facebook, url, twitter, web-crawler

I am scratching my head

Take a (new) twitter url, ex. [http://twitter.com/#!/NASA] (notice the "#!")

Paste this link on your Facebook wall or the "What's on your mind?" input box on the main Facebook page.

After it crawls the link, look at what link this resolves to. It's not the correct twitter url.  Last night it resolved to [http://twitter.com/#!/d3nidhint] and now it's resolving to [http://twitter.com/#!/_hKnbln] (the former resolves to a twitter page, the latter does not). What gives?

Facebook clearly parses this url and resolves it as something different. If it can do this much, it should resolve the url to the proper twitter page. I searched online and came up with Google links that propose crawling these AJAX urls, but nothing having to do with this weird anomoly: [http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/] and [http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html]

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this is happening is because Twitter switched their permalinks like http:// twitter.com/RWW to http:// twitter.com/#!/RWW and the Facebook crawler thinks its just all an update to the same page http:// twitter.com/ so you get whatever was cached last. They will need to update their crawler to replace the #! out. It would be great if this was a standard practice for all people doing ajax navigation.

ps - Added space because stack overflow thinks all my links are spam - LOL